# What is the best way to convert a JSZip object to an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, jszip

My application compresses user submitted files into zip files, using JSZip. I then want to use the Leaflet.shapefile plugin to display the zip file on my application.

However, the constructor only accepts ArrayBuffer. I looked at the docs for JSZip, and while there is support for ArrayBuffers, I can't find any explicit methods for converting a JSZip object into an ArrayBuffer.

```
function CreateZipFile(Files)
{
    Response.type = "ArrayBuffer";
    let zip = new JSZip();

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(Files).length; i++)
    {
        if (!CheckShapeExtensions(Files[i].name))
        {
            continue;
        }
        zip.file(Files[i].name, Files[i]);
    }

    zip.generateAsync({
        type: 'blob',
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
            level: 9
        },
        name: zipfileName + ".zip"
    });

    return zip;
}
```

Because the returned zip is not an array buffer, operations that accepts the zip file would throw the following error.

```
leaflet.shpfile.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArrayBuffer' of undefined
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet.shpfile.js:13)
    at new NewClass (Class.js:22)
    at Object.L.shapefile (leaflet.shpfile.js:62)
    at filescan (Account_2.js:115)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Account:156)
```

How should I convert the JSZip file into an ArrayBuffer? If not, should I write the zip file as an array buffer instead of a JSZip object?

Comment: change `type: "blob"` to `type: "arrayBuffer"`?

Comment: Hi @Endless, tried that. It didn't work. The zip file returned is still a JSZip object and not an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: Your error states that  whatever you called `isArrayBuffer` on is `undefined`. This means your problem lies at *line 13* of *leaflet.shpfile.js*, not yet in the the format your data is exposed.

Comment: GenerateAsync returns a promise with the new blob/arraybuffer, yet you are ignoring the result

Answer (score 0):

```js
function CheckShapeExtensions(file) {
  return true
}

function CreateZipFile (files) {
  const zip = new JSZip()

  Array.from(files)
    .filter(CheckShapeExtensions)
    .forEach(file => {
      zip.file(file.name, file)
    })

  // generateAsync returns a promise,
  // means it is async
  return zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'arrayBuffer', // changed from blob to arrayBuffer
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    compressionOptions: {
      level: 9
    }
  })
}

// Simulate files you would get from a file input
// const files = input.files
const files = { 0: new File(['abc'], 'abc.txt'), length: 1 }

CreateZipFile(files).then(arrayBuffer => {
  console.log(arrayBuffer.toString())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://stuk.github.io/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
```